# How to overlay text + image over each item in a flex container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to have something like this:

[image]

As you can see, each tile has a different image and text over it. I'm given a list of file names from backend - the text is the file name, the little image corresponds to the file extension. So, I don't think this would be just a simple listing of items within a flex container, I'd need to dynamically overlay appropriate image + text over each tile (each tile is a Mask).

How can I accomplish this?

UPDATE:

```
.file_img.generic {
    width: 45.7px;
    height: 53px;
    background-image: url(../../Images/file-generic.png)
}
```

UPDATE 2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSm1b.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8MQ1.png)

UPDATE 3:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcHbb.png)

1. The separation between the tiles are non-existent. I tried a couple different justify content rules but they all end up looking wonky.
2. The image is aligned to the left with the text to the right of it, but I wanted it so that the image is centered as shown above, with the text right below it. How do I accomplish that?
3. For some reason, the opacity on the text doesn't work. I try toggling the CSS rule and nothing changes.

The relevant HTML:

```
<div>
            <p className="Title">DocVault</p>
            <p className="Subtitle">Placeholder {this.props.address.address}</p>
            <ul className="flex-container"> {
                this.state.files.map(file => (
                    <div className="Tile">
                        <div className = {
                            `file_img${this.getFileExtension(file)}`
                        }></div>
                        <p className="File_Name">{file}</p>
                    </div>
                ))
            }
            </ul>
```

The relevant CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: HiraKakuPro-W3;
    src: url(../../Fonts/hiragino-kaku-pro-w3.otf) format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: HiraKakuPro-W6;
    src: url(../../Fonts/hiragino-kaku-pro-w6.otf) format("opentype");
}

.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.File-Name {
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-family: HiraKakuProN-W3;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.33;
    letter-spacing: 0.69px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #787993;
}

.Tile {
    display:flex;
    width: 165px;
    height: 165px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(37, 38, 94, 0.1);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.file_imgfolder {
    background-size: 100%;

    width: 53px;
    height: 44.9px;
    background-size: 100%;

    background-image: url(../../Images/file-folder.png)
}

.file_imgxlsx {

    width: 46px;
    height: 53px;
    background-size: 100%;

    background-image: url(../../Images/file-csv.png)
}

.file_imgpdf {

    width: 45px;
    height: 53px;
    background-size: 100%;

    background-image: url(../../Images/file-pdf.png)
}

.file_imggeneric {
    width: 45.7px;
    height: 53px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url(../../Images/file-generic.png)
}
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you provide your code?

Comment: Well I don't know where to start with this, I'm assuming it's some kind of CSS rule or HTML aspect that I'm just ignorant of. I mean I know how to add a flex container and appropriately append items to it, but not how I want it in this specific scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post you current code and the way the file list comes back from the backend, so it's hard to imply exactly how you would do it, but this is how I would do it based on the information you provided.

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
state = {
    fileList = [
        {
            fileName: "file_name.pdf",
        },
        {
            fileName: "other_file_name.xlsx",
        }
    ]
}
```

I would create a function that returns the file extension

```
// get file extension (pass fileName)

getFileExtension(fileName) => fileName.slice(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') +1)
```

This will return just the file extension.

Then it your html (react) code

```
<div className="file_list_wrpr">
    {
        this.state.fileList.map(file => (
            <div className="file_wrpr">
                <div className={`file_img ${this.getFileExtension(file.fileName)}`} />
                <p className="file_name pdf">file_name.pdf</p>
            </div>
        ))
    }
</div>
```

Then you can create a css class for each file type like this:

```
.file_list_wrpr {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.file_wrpr {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.file_img {
    height: 30px;
    width:30px;
}

.file_img.pdf {
    background-image: url('path_to_your_pdf_icon')
}

.file_img.xlsx{
    background-image: url('path_to_your_excel_icon')
}
```

Sorry for the long answer.

Also it may not give you the exact style you are looking for for it should give you the basic idea

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Hey this is pretty helpful, only thing is my images aren't actually displaying. The className gets appropriately changed, (so that part of setting the file_img class works as it should), but I guess something about the CSS rules isn't right I guess. I updated the OP with how I styled one of the images

Comment: Can you show me more about the css for the image? Do you know the image size? If the image is larger then the div (in my example more then 30px X 30px) you need to either resize the image in photoshop etc. or set `.file_img { background-size: 100% .....}` in css. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I tried setting background-size to 100% but still no luck. Each of these pictures are around 174px x 200px

Comment: Can you post a link to a screenshot of the html and css in the chrome inspector tool? So I can have a better idea of what the issue is.

Comment: Updated OP with screenshots of the HTML and CSS

Comment: In the HTML there is a `.` in the `class="file_img.xlsx"` not sure where that is coming from but there should be a space and not the `.`. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: That did the trick - thanks - I just had a few more questions about how the styling turned out that I'm not sure if it has to do with the CSS styling that's going on or if my React code is doing something weird to it. I updated OP with details, if you can help in any way that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the separation you may want to add `margin: 4px 8px` to `.Tile` (you can adjust the number according to your needs), For #2 you need to add '`flex-flow: column;` to `.Tile`, For the last one I'm not sure but maybe check the casing of `.File-Name` mayby its `.file-name` or something? (you can also try with a lower number like `opacity:0.2` to make sure if it works or not). You may also want to keep the text to one line and trim if it's too long? for that you need to add `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; max-width: 90%;` to `.File-Name`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Just for future reference, how do you know all of these rules and the specifics?

Comment: My pleasure, It comes with a few years of experience, here is a good reference https://css-tricks.com, Also looking around on the web, inspect elements etc. Also I'm available any time if you need more help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to split the file name, and then add the corresponding title,
find the documentation here [a link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: This isn't the problem. I'm already given a list of strings.